# bootstrap jquery twitter bootstrap locally

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to adapt source code for my purposes, it is mandatory to download and use bootstrap, jquery and bootstrap locally, so I've downloaded all of them to a directory called "libs", when I try to execute the PHP file those libraries are not loaded, the problem is in these lines:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/libs/bs337/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/jquery311/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/tbs4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/twbs/jquery.twbsPagination.min.js"></script>
<script src="/libs/bsval/validator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/toastr/toastr.min.js"></script>
<link href="/libs/toastr/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I use them from the Web everything works, just like that:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twbs-pagination/1.3.1/jquery.twbsPagination.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.5/validator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

All those libraries are downloaded and in a separately directories for each one, what else should I do in order to use those libraries without be online?

Regards

Comment: are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Its a problem with the path. In production this work, but in local doesn't. Where you have the files? do you try without `/`? `src="libs/twbs/jquery.twbsPagination.min.js"`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the / before the libs directory.
src="/libs/jquery311/jquery.js">

Comment: I've already tried to Remove the "/" before the calls to the libraries, but it does not work. The page is call "index.php", it is under the root menu and the directory "libs" is inside the root directory

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my mistake, it was about directory permission issue, I used the browser console and I saw a 403 error, then check in my MATE console -I am working on a GNU/Linux Debian box- then I used properly permission and problem solved. Thanks for your time